# Determining black pixels as white in matlab

Tags: matlab, pixel

I have the black-white image. When I view particular `coordinate (x,y)` of this image in Image Viewer I could see that it has value `0`. However, when I want to obtain value from `(x,y)` in my script I get `255`. Code looks as following:

```
    bw = imread('my_map.png');
    imshow(bw);
    hold on
    % find corners of obstacles
    corners = detectHarrisFeatures(bw);
    plot(corners.selectStrongest(50));
    cornerPoints = corners.selectStrongest(50);
    hold on
    % determine line's equation for two particular corners
    m = cornerPoints.Location(4,2)-cornerPoints.Location(3,2);
    n = cornerPoints.Location(4,1)-cornerPoints.Location(3,1);
    k = (m)/(n);
    b = cornerPoints.Location(3,2) - k*cornerPoints.Location(3,1);

    %determine if this line intersects any obstacle
    black = 0;
    white = 0;
    for y=cornerPoints.Location(3,2):1:cornerPoints.Location(4,2)

        x = (y-b)/k;
        if (int16(x) == 0)
            x = cornerPoints.Location(3,1);
        end
         plot(int16(x),int16(y),'r*')
         hold on
        c = bw(int16(x), int16(y));
        if (c==255)
            white=white+1;

        else
            black=black+1;
        end
    end
    if (white == 0)
        display('valid')

    else if (black <= 2)
        display('valid')
    else
        display('invalid')
    end
```

The image is this

[image: this one].

What might be the problem?

Comment: I would suggest you add some code. Otherwise I don't think you'll get an answer.

Comment: you probably need to pay attention to the coordinates system origin. Also remember that MATLAB uses 1-based indexing

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab, the first coordinate of a matrix represents a row index, and the second one represents a column index.

Therefore, in order to access to point (x,y) of a matrix M, i.e. with row index y and column index x, you need to write:

```
M(y,x)
```

In your case, you should write:

```
c = bw(int16(y), int16(x));
```

instead of:

```
c = bw(int16(x), int16(y));
```

Comment: [How it looks like after x and y exchange](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ud1wo0o1o8iwg07/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202016-04-18%2000.48.52.png?dl=0). Something goes wrong. The red line must go from the blue star to the red star.

Comment: Again, it's a mix up between the x and y values - look the (x,y) coordinates of your line, and the (x,y) coordinates of the red and blue star, they are exactly the opposite from one another.